# Render single band gray raster define gradient and cumulative cut

Tags: qgis, python

I want to save an image with these characteristics:

- gradient: white to black
- std deviation = 5

Until now I get to apply the gradient but the minimum and maximum values are used instead of cumulative cut of 2% to 98%.

My code is this:

```
fileInfo_slope = QFileInfo(slope)
layerName_slope = fileInfo_slope.baseName()
slope_ = QgsRasterLayer(slope, layerName_slope)  

provider = slope_.dataProvider()
Renderer = QgsSingleBandGrayRenderer(provider,1)
band = Renderer.grayBand()    

layerType = slope_.type()
rasterType = slope_.rasterType()
renderType = slope_.renderer()
myType = renderType.dataType(band)

myMin,myMax = provider.cumulativeCut( band, 0.02, 0.98)
myEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement(myType)
myEnhancement.setMinimumValue( myMin )
myEnhancement.setMaximumValue( myMax )  
renderType.setContrastEnhancement(myEnhancement)
Renderer.setGradient(1)
slope_.setRenderer(Renderer)
if hasattr(slope_, "setCacheImage"): 
    slope_.setCacheImage(None)
slope_.triggerRepaint()
```

But when the map (slope) is created I don't want the minimum/maximum values but the cumulative cut. In this example I try to modify the cumulative values but I get no success. Can you help me?